# Unity Lighting Problems

Tags: unity, c#, lighting, shadows

I've got a problem with the settings of lighting in my unity scene.

The objects have got "dark sides" and it doesn't look natural.

You can see the screenshots and my light settings here:

The screenshot that shows the problem

[image: The screenshot that shows the problem]

[image: Lighting settings]

[image: Sun settings]

Comment: This looks like it might be adequately answered by [some of our existing Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/163326/how-to-avoid-completely-dark-shadow-using-directional-light-as-sun). Take a look through the answers so far to see if they can solve your problem. If you're still having trouble, you can edit your question to clarify where the existing answers aren't giving the desired results, and we can re-open the question for more targeted fixes.